# Are C standard library structures compatible between compilers and library versions on macOS or Linux?

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, clang

My host application took over the ownership of e.g. a FILE object which came from a dynamic library. Can I call `fclose()` on this object safely even though my host application and the dynamic library are compiled with different versions of clang / gcc?

### Background

On Windows (with different VS runtimes) it would be illegal and I have to first extract the `fclose()` function from the runtime library which is used by the dynamic library since all runtimes have their own pools and internal structures for file or memory objects.

An illustration for the situation in Windows would look like this:

[image: diagram of library interactions on Windows]

Does this restriction apply for Linux and macOS as well?

Comment: Is it just me, or it is completely unclear what you are talking about?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's just you. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit That's why I asked :) Wasn't sure. But its just me +2 people

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Or (now) three people are happy you are confused.

Comment: I would hate to live in a world where I can't write a function that returns a `FILE *`, for fear that my caller can't close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not whether your application and the dynamic libraries were compiled with different versions of clang and/or gcc.  The issue is whether, ultimately, there's one underlying C library that manipulates one kind of FILE * object and has one, compatible implementation of `fclose()`.

Under MacOS and Linux, at least, the answer to all these questions is likely to be "yes".  In my experience it's hard to get two different, incompatible C libraries into the mix; you'd have to really work at it.

---

Addendum: I suppose I should admit, however, that my experience may be getting dated.  In my experience, on any Unix-like system, there's exactly one C library, generally `/lib/libc.{a,so}`.  But I gather that "modern" compilers are tending to access their own compiler- and version-specific libraries off in special places, meaning that the scenario you're worried about could be a problem.  To me, it seems, this way lies madness, but then again, it seems that more and more of the world seems to be embracing [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell), rather than trying to eliminate it.

Comment: For my example I mistakenly assumed that two different compiler versions would automatically mean two different and incompatible C libraries. So from your answer I read that most of the different C library versions are still compatible to each other and safe to use?

Comment: A system normally has just one standard library, and compiling your code with different compilers doesn't change it. If you use a compiler that's incompatible with your system's stdlib, you're in trouble already.

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, it's true that using two different compilers does *not* necessarily result in accessing two incompatible C libraries.  But if you do end accessing two incompatible C libraries, then yes, you're bound to have lots of trouble.

Comment: It is not correct that “The issue is whether, ultimately, there’s one underlying C library…” When a program calls a standard library function named `foo`, the resulting object code does not necessarily contain instructions to call `foo`. They might call `fooX`, which is, for example, some optimized variant the compiler decided was suitable for the particular situation in which the source code called `foo`. That `fooX` would exist in the library designed to be used with the compiler but not in another compiler’s library. And that is only one example of incompatibilities that can occur.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand that issue, but to me the fundamental question here is whether that scenario can be considered to be the norm or not.  In my experience it has *not* been, and this did indeed mean that compiler and library authors could not avail themselves of the opportunity to introduce dependencies such as you describe.  Today, with the accelerating adoption of dependency hell as the norm, it's harder to say.

Comment: Thanks! Especially your addendum underpinned my suspicion. I am not sure yet how to address that issue yet, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

It is not generally safe to use a library designed for one compiler with code compiled by a different compiler. A compiler may generate code that implements the nominal functions in the standard library using internal routines or interfaces, and those routines or interfaces may be different or missing in the library designed for another compiler.

Nor is it safe to take any pointer to some internal data structure from one library and use it with another library.

If the sources are just compiled with different versions of one compiler (e.g., clang 73 and clang 89), not different compilers (e.g., Apple clang versus GCC), the compiler might offer some guarantee about library compatibility. You would have to check its documentation. Or, if the compiler is intended to use the library provided with the operating system, that could work. Again, you would have to check its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, if both your code and the other library dynamically link to the same library (such as `libc.so.6`), both will get the same version and implementation of that library at runtime.  You can check which libraries a given dynamic library links to with `ldd`.

If you were linking to a library that statically linked in a supporting library, you would need to be careful to pass any structures to or from it against the same version of the library.  But this is more likely to come up in practice with `libc++` and `libstdc++` than with `libc`.

So, don't statically link your library to another and then pass a data structure that requires client code to separately link to the same library.